# How to find the nearest time in SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server

```
id     Bus arrival time
1          6:30
2          7:00
3          9:00
4          10:00
5          15:00
6          16:00
```

If one bus comes at 6:40 then nearest time should be 6:30

If bus comes at 9:35 nearest time should be 10:00 like wise I need the solution as a T-SQL  query

Thanks In Advance,
Anil

Comment: How are you storing the `Bus arrival time` data? What date-type are you using?

Answer (score 4):

```
declare @checkTime time = '6:40'

select top 1 * from schedule
order by ABS(DATEDIFF(Second, @checkTime, busArrivalTime))
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eb020/8)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like :

```
DECLARE @TIME TIME = '6:45'


DECLARE @TEMP TABLE(ID int,start time);

insert into @temp values(1, '6:30')
insert into @temp values(1, '7:00')
insert into @temp values(1, '9:00')
insert into @temp values(1, '10:00')
insert into @temp values(1, '15:00')
insert into @temp values(1, '6:30')
insert into @temp values(1, '16:00')


SELECT top(1)start ,ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE , @TIME ,START )) as diff
FROM @TEMP
order by diff
```

Comment: is this query helpful to you ??

Comment: Here's a hint: set `@TIME` to `8:45` and test